# If the tiny square has $3cm$ side, what would be the total area of the big rectangle?

Tags: area, quadrilateral, rectangles

If the tiny square has $3cm$ side, what would be the total area of the big rectangle?

[image]

Comment: It's impossible to tell unless you give us more information? What properties do the individual squares have? Do they relate to the one with a side length of $3$ cm? Otherwise your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: HINT Give each square a unique number (i.e. $1$ through $10$) and let $x_i$ be the length of the side of square $i$. Now write down the equalities that you have of the form $x_i+x_j=x_k$ ... and solve that system of equations. ... assuming it is solvable ...

Answer (score 1):

Googleing "rectangle of squares", I've found the solution.
You can just start calling some side $x$ and writing out everything you know, using pretty much only that the four sides of a square have equal length.
You get:
[image]

I found it here: http://www.pleacher.com/mp/probweek/p2016/a0316a.html
You can find $x$ by equating the top and the bottom of the rectangle. 
You'll get: $65 \times 47 = 3055$.

Comment: You still need to solve for $x$ to get an actual solution.

Comment: How do you get $x$ by equating the top and bottom of the rectangle?

Comment: Yeah, I realized that a few seconds after posting my answer :)

Comment: @Bram28 Because the top is $3x-1$ while the bottom is $6x-67$.

Comment: @Arthur Ah yes, I see it now. It would've helped if they had added the last $x+2$ and $3x-43$ into the figure. Thanks!

Comment: @Bram28 Yes, it could've been more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Choose a square (near the $3$) and call it $x$ keep doing linear algebra until you get an equation that $x$ satisfies.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution appears at the top of the Mathworld page [Perfect Rectangle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerfectRectangle.html), which in turn has a link to a [database of solutions](http://www.squaring.net/). The area is $3055$.

In the database it's found under Simple Perfect Squared Rectangles, where it's one of just six rectangles that can be formed using exactly $10$ squares of distinct sizes.